# Using Array.map() on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use Array.map to slice the `description` property of each object within an array.

```
docs = docs.map(function(currentValue, index, array){
            currentValue['description'] = currentValue.description.slice(0,10);
            return array;
        });
```

When I `console.log(docs)` it appears as though it has worked. However, I can no longer access the properties for some reason.

```
console.log(docs[0].description); //undefined
```

It appears that I have turned my array of objects into an array of strings that appear to be objects. Any thoughts?

Comment: In that case, what you need to use is `each` not `map()` as you are not doing any transformation of the items in the array

Comment: Works fine for me - Firefox 43.0.3 -> https://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/o9evwjmg/

Comment: @rockerest: It worked because you didn't assign the garbage array returned by `map` back into `docs`, so it ended up being equivalent to a `forEach` loop (it just made the temp array and threw it away).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I mutated the code when I was filling in the missing info from the question. It did NOT work for me :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The callback in `.map` shouldn't return `array` -- it should return the new value you want that particular item in the array to have.

```
docs = docs.map(function(item){
  item.description = item.description.slice(0, 10);
  return item;
});
```

If all you're doing is transforming each item in the array, it would be more performant to use `.forEach` instead. `.map` creates a *whole new array*, whereas `.forEach` simply loops through the existing array. It also takes less code.

```
docs.forEach(function(item){
  item.description = item.description.slice(0, 10);
});
```

Comment: I think author needs to save changed `docs` so he used `.map`

Answer (score 1):

It is because you return `array` in map instead of `currentValue`.
It should be

```
docs = docs.map(function(currentValue, index, array){
        currentValue['description'] = currentValue.description.slice(0,10);
        return currentValue;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, what you need to use is [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) not [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as you are not doing any transformation of the items in the array

```
docs.forEach(function(currentValue, index, array){
    currentValue['description'] = currentValue.description.slice(0,10);
});
```

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used to transform each item in an array and return a new object, since in your case you are just changing a property of each item, there is no need to use it.

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach()`  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
docs = docs.map(function(currentValue, index, array){
        docs[index]['description'] = currentValue.description.slice(0,10);
        return array;
    });
```

I think it should be like this.